# My UIVIEW creating by Storyboard ,but my drawRect can not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to draw a circle. I create a subclass of `UIView` named `timeView`, and I set the class of the `UIView` is `TimeView`. But there is no showing.

```
 #import "TimeView.h"

 @implementation TimeView


        -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
            CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
           //中心
            CGPoint center;
            center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width/ 2.0;
            center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height/ 2.0;
           //圆的半径
            float radius = (MIN(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height));

            UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

            [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2.0
                         clockwise:YES ];

            path.lineWidth = 10;
            [[UIColor blackColor ]setStroke];
            [path stroke];
        }

        @end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: hhhh, i just start learn ios by myself,i am a fresh man ,obviously,i should learn more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code is correct and its drawing a circle. The issue is with the math logic to calculate the radius. The circle is too big to fit in that view.

```
float radius = (MIN(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height))/2;
```

Use the following to calculate the radius and it should work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get the current drawing context and draw into that...

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]));
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: seem like drawRect do not be called

Comment: CG stands for core graphics. I use it too, in a view subclass that I tested this code in. It definitely works. If drawRect isn't called, you might need to cause it, with [theCircleDrawingView setNeedsDisplay] in the vc that controls that view.